# Difficulty with filtering two lists in SML

Tags: list, sml

I'm trying to "double" filter through two lists depending on passing a datatype test painfully without recursion using HOPs.  Below is my very-ugly attempt at a solution...

```
datatype 'a test = Test of ('a -> bool) * string;

fun foo xs lst = 
    let 
        fun foo_bar(x, ls) =
            let                
                val tests = (List.filter (fn (Test(f, str)) => (f x)) ls)
            in
                (List.map (fn (Test(f, str)) => str) tests)
            end 
    in
        (List.map (fn x => foo_bar(x, lst)) xs)
    end;
```

```
allPass: 'a list -> 'a test list -> 'a test list;
```

`allPass [1, 2, 40, 150] [positive, even]` should return the string `"pos"`.

Currently, my function is returning a nested list: `[["pos"], ["pos even"], ["pos even"], ["pos even"]]`.  Is there a non-recursive way to extract just "pos" from this result or am I going about solving this problem in entirely the wrong direction?

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate a bit on why you would expect the function to return only a single result, instead of the list of results it does now. Also you have defined a `foo` function, but are using a `allPass` function in you example case.

Comment: Note that the map and fold functions are available in the top level environment, thus you don't need to write `List.map`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going in the right direction, but you're not quite there yet. Here's what I think you want.

Take a list of value and a list of Tests. Return a list of the names of the tests for which *all* of the values pass.

Okay, so we need to:

1. Filter the list of tests. The predicate for a test is that all the values must pass.
2. Extract the names of the tests that passed.

Okay, so how do we figure out if all the values in a list pass one test? Simple, we use `List.all`.

```
List.all    : ('a -> bool) -> 'a list -> bool
```

We can define a function:

```
fun allPassesTest xs (Test(f,s)) = List.all f xs
```

This will return `true` if and only if all of the values in xs pass the test. Now we filter the list of tests, based on this function:

```
fun allPass xs tests = List.filter allPassesTest xs tests
```

However, this returns a `'a test list` instead of a `string list`, so you'll need to extract the names.

```
fun name (Test(f,s)) = s
fun allPass xs tests = map name (List.filter allPassesTest xs tests)
```